# Processing skipping every other

Tags: processing, xbee

I am trying to group segments of the XBee output into a variable that joins them. I am using [Processing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processing_%28programming_language%29) to code and compile. The issue I am having is that the output (println) is skipping every other byte (maybe that's the wrong term). So XBee output for i = 4 though 11 should look like this:

> 0,19,162,0,64,121,230,206 (this is the XBee address converted from hex).

But the println shows this:

> 19,0,121,206,125,1,0,3 (which starts getting into other segments of the output).

Later, I tried a different route by using an array. It still skips every other entry and I've found that it has to do with my check for i == 126. Is there an alternate way of doing a check like this?

Substitute this draw section for the one below. It's simpler to follow. This was a test with same results...

```
void draw() {
    if (myPort.available() > 21) {
        int[] XBeeAddr = new int[22];
        for (int i=0; i<22; i++) {
            XBeeAddr[i] = myPort.read();
            if (myPort.read == 126) {
                i=0;
            }
        println(XBeeAddr[0] + "," + XBeeAddr[1] + "," + XBeeAddr[2]);
    }
}
```

#### Original code

```
import processing.serial.*;
import de.bezier.data.sql.*; // For SQLite database

SQLite db; // For SQLite database
Serial myPort;

void setup() {
    println(Serial.list());
    myPort = new Serial(this, Serial.list()[0],9600);

    // For SQLite database...
    size( 100, 100 );
    db = new SQLite( this, "test.db" );  // Open database file
    if ( db.connect() ) {
        String[] tableNames = db.getTableNames();
        db.query( "SELECT * FROM %s", tableNames[0] );
        while (db.next()) {
            TableOne t = new TableOne();
            db.setFromRow( t );
            println( t );
        }
    }
}

// For SQLite database
class TableOne {
    public String fieldOne;
    public int fieldTwo;
    public String toString () {
        return String.format("fieldOne: %s fieldTwo: %d", fieldOne, fieldTwo);
    }
}

void draw() {
    if (myPort.available() > 21) {
        int XBeeAddr1 = 0;
        int XBeeAddr2 = 0;
        int XBeeAddr3 = 0;
        int XBeeAddr4 = 0;
        int XBeeAddr5 = 0;
        int XBeeAddr6 = 0;
        int XBeeAddr7 = 0;
        int XBeeAddr8 = 0;

        for (int i=0; i<22; i++) {
            int inByte = myPort.read();
            if (inByte == 126) {
                i=0; // This resets the counter if XBee data was incomplete on the last run.
            }
            if (i == 4) {
                XBeeAddr1 = myPort.read();
            }
            if (i == 5) {
                XBeeAddr2 = myPort.read();
            }
            if (i == 6) {
                XBeeAddr3 = myPort.read();
            }
            if (i == 7) {
                XBeeAddr4 = myPort.read();
            }
            if (i == 8) {
                XBeeAddr5 = myPort.read();
            }
            if (i == 9) {
                XBeeAddr6 = myPort.read();
            }
            if (i == 10) {
                XBeeAddr7 = myPort.read();
            }
            if (i == 11) {
                XBeeAddr8 = myPort.read();
            }

            String XBeeAddrAll = XBeeAddr1 + "," + 
                                 XBeeAddr2 + "," + 
                                 XBeeAddr3 + "," + 
                                 XBeeAddr4 + "," + 
                                 XBeeAddr5 + "," + 
                                 XBeeAddr6 + "," + 
                                 XBeeAddr7 + "," + 
                                 XBeeAddr8;
            println(XBeeAddrAll);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It was fixed by changing `myPort.read == 126` to `if XBeeAddr[0] != 126, break`. Then later I did an `if XBeeAddr[0] == 126 println`.